# How to get the dataset size of a Caffe net in python?

Tags: neural-network, deep-learning, caffe, lmdb, pycaffe

I look at the python [example for Lenet](https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/blob/master/examples/mnist/lenet_solver.prototxt) and see that the number of iterations needed to run over the entire MNIST test dataset is hard-coded. However, can this value be not hard-coded at all? How to get the number of samples of the dataset pointed by a network in python?

Comment: what is your input layer? LMDB/levelDB/HDF5?

Comment: The LeNet example uses LMDB by default for the MNIST database.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [`lmdb`](https://lmdb.readthedocs.org/en/release) library to access the lmdb directly

```
import lmdb
db = lmdb.open('/path/to/lmdb_folder')       //Needs lmdb - method
num_examples = int( db.stat()['entries'] )
```

Should do the trick for you.

Comment: Then is there a way to know the dataset path & format that is used by the net?

Comment: @user1735003 try and play with the caffe proto interface to parse the prototxt

Comment: Mmh, `caffe_pb2` seems like a huge mess. I *think* you can check which DB you are using through `NetParameter.layer[0].data_param.DB.values()` assuming you know which layer is the data layer, and then this checks only for LMDB or LEVELDB formats. I have not been able to find the path to the test db yet, any hint would help.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you mixed **iterations** and **amount of samples** in one question. In the provided [example](https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/blob/master/examples/mnist/lenet_solver.prototxt) we can see only number of **iterations**, i. e. how many times training phase will be repeated. The is no any direct relationship between amount of **iterations** (network training parameters) and amount of **samples** in dataset (network input).

Some more detailed explanation:

**EDIT**: **Caffe** will totally load (**batch size** x **iterations**) samples for training or testing, but there is no relation with **amount of loaded samples** and **actual database size**: it will start reading from the beginning after reaching database last record - it other words, database in **caffe** acts like a [circular buffer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_buffer).

Mentioned example points to [this configuration](https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/blob/master/examples/mnist/lenet_train_test.prototxt). We can see that it expects **lmdb** input, and sets *batch size* to **64** (some more info about [batches and BLOBs](http://caffe.berkeleyvision.org/tutorial/net_layer_blob.html)) for **training** phase and **100** for **testing** phase. Really we don't make any assumption about input **dataset size**, i. e. **number of samples in dataset**: *batch size* is only processing chunk size, *iterations* is how many batches **caffe** will take. It won't stop after reaching database end.

In other words, network itself (i. e. *protobuf* config files) doesn't point to any number of samples **in database** - only to dataset name and format and *desired* amount of samples. There is no way to determine **database size** with **caffe** at the current moment, as I know.

Thus if you want to load entire dataset for testing, you have only option to firstly determine **amount of samples** in *mnist_test_lmdb* or *mnist_train_lmdb* manually, and then specify corresponding values for **batch size** and **iterations**.

You have some options for this:

1. Look at `./examples/mnist/create_mnist.sh` console output - it prints amount of samples while converting from initial format (I believe that you followed [this tutorial](http://caffe.berkeleyvision.org/gathered/examples/mnist.html));
2. follow @Shai's advice (read lmdb file directly).

Comment: "The is no any direct relationship between amount of iterations (network training parameters) and amount of samples in dataset (network input)." Well, `#test_samples = #test_batch * #test_iter`, doesn't that count for a relationship? (I assume one wants to use the entire test dataset to test, of course).

Comment: OK, possibly I was slightly unclear... I mean that **caffe** know nothing about *database size* (lmdb in our case). **Caffe** loads data chunk-by-chunk and doesn't care about actual position in database: when it reaches database last record, it starts from the beginning. Of course amount of samples will be `batch_size * iterations_num`, but there won't be **different** samples. I. e. with caffe I don't see any possibility to get database size. I edited my answer accordingly.